# Laravel 5.2 - Always downloading same file even if I change the path

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my controller function:

```
public function showFile()
{
    $path = $this->user->path;

    return response()->download($path);
}
```

After I change the path in DB, Laravel is still downloading the same previous file. Some minutes later Laravel returns the correct file. Why?

Thanks;

Comment: Is not Laravel problem. CloudFlare stuff ...

Comment: Same problem in mine Laravel 4.2. #abel did you found any solution for this?

Comment: In my case, Laravel was not the problem. CloudFlare was caching the resource. I solved it generating urls uniques.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for reverting back. Yea you were right, Laravel was not problem. I solved mine too. Thank a lot.